# Looking for instructions on how to structure a single page application

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, code-structure

We are a team of developers that have been doing web application programming for a few years. We are now starting over with a new project and we are aiming at making it a single page application. For the front end we are using angular. We are relatively familiar with angular, we know how to create services, directives, controllers ect. We know how to use built in services like `$http` and `$resource` and how to user routes (or states with [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)) but we are stuck at a pretty early state on how to structure the application.

We are having a hard time finding good resources (blogs, videos, books) that tackle this general issue. Many posts have a very simple approach like:

"To build a SPA you need to use `$http`, this is how you do it, easy isn't it?"

They can be very good to understand the basics of each component but they do not explain hos to couple it all together. Questions we have are of the following type:

- Do we build a central js object to represent the application state? If the application would be a back end for a web shop then the central object would probably be a company which has a list of products, each having a list of orders and each of them has a reference to the customer. Or do we split the representation of the application state in different objects? If so, how do we keep them in sync?
- To display a form which edits an entity we create a route that loads a partial into a view and we populate the scope with the entity to edit. Do we fetch the entity from the back end? Or if we already have it in our js model, do we simply fetch it from there so that we don't need to make an http request?

There is a lot more that is unclear and I realize that there will not be a simple answer to any question, rather it is likely to be different design patterns with pros and cons. I do not expect the answers to all my questions as a response to this post, but rather I'd like to find some resource (like I said blog, video, book) that discuss these issues on an application-wide level. Some questions are angular-specific and some are more general around single page applications. Are there such resources?

Comment: This is my exact question. How did you go about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I have not found a good resource yet. Right now our approach is to try different approaches across the application as we develop it further. We do automated testing very thoroughly, both unit and e2e. This allows us to change the internals of the application as long as all tests pass. By doing it this way we learn as we go what fits us. We also decided not to use ngResource or restangular but instead to build everything from scratch. When we se a pattern we will probably choose a framework that suits us. This is my best advice for now...

Answer (score 3):

I am relatively new to AngularJS myself, and I agree it is hard to find info that goes beyond the basics.  So far, the most useful tutorials I have found are from Dan Wahlin.

- http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/04/12/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx
- http://blogs.interfacett.com/getting-started-with-angularjs-video-series

The 60-ish minute tutorial was excellent, and his other stuff is good for getting you past the Hello World stage.  I've also watch a couple presentations from Misko Hevery, the creator of Angular, and he is very good too.